# Escaping white spaces in nestedExpr pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

```
import pyparsing as pp
print(pp.nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")").parseString("(account={eq:T 1 No Lim})", parseAll=True)[0])
```

Above code gives me below output:

`['account={eq:T', '1', 'No', 'Lim}']`

But I want to escape white spaces from value part and want below output:

`[u'account={eq:T 1 No Lim}']`

Can anyone please suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can make use of `originalTextFor`.

For example:

```
import pyparsing as pp
print(pp.originalTextFor(pp.nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")")).parseString("(account={eq:T 1 No Lim})", parseAll=True)[0])
```

Comment: this returns original "(" and ")" as it is .we don't want it .

Comment: we can't use print to hide it if we want to store it in some other variable

Comment: Removing the enclosing ()'s can be done on the returned results (`print(result[0][1:-1])` or can be done in the parser using a parse action: `parser = pp.originalTextFor(pp.nestedExpr()).addParseAction(lambda t: t[0][1:-1])`. Please use the green check mark to accept this answer, they have given you a good solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`[u'account={eq:T1NoLim}']`  is the output when i used `"(account={eq:T1NoLim})"`  in example string But when i used `"(account={eq:T 1 No Lim})"`  then getting below output
`['account={eq:T', '1', 'No', 'Lim}']`